# Can you suggest the best screencast available to learn CSS?

Tags: css

It should be hands-on, complete, targeted to programmers and detailed on layout techniques!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out www.css-tricks.com.  They have excellent screen casts.

Another place to check out is the various web design podcasts.  Go to iTunes and search the podcasts and you will probably find a few to check out.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few that you might like to consider:

- **[CSS for Designers](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modPage.asp?id=216)** with: Andy Clarke and Molly E. Holzschlag
- **[CSS Web Site Design](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modPage.asp?ID=279)** with: Eric Meyer
- **[SitePoint :The CSS Video Crash Course](http://www.sitepoint.com/videos/videocss1/)**
- **[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/videos/)**
- **[Beginners CSS Tutorial](http://www.softwaretrainingtutorials.com/css2.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a free screen cast? If not, Eric Meyer (one of the gods of web standards)  has a video called [CSS Web Design](http://www.lynda.com/store/productinfo.aspx?productid=532) which will tell you everything you need to be fluent with CSS.

It also covers some advanced CSS techniques like [Sliding Doors](http://www.lynda.com/store/productinfo.aspx?productid=532). He also goes and refactors some HTML on some well known websites to take advantage of CSS.

If you are a fast learner, [W3School's CSS](http://w3schools.com/css/) section has more than enough information to get you started. CSS is actually very easy to learn.